# doodle (verb & noun) scribble absent-mindedly/ a rough drawing made absent-mindedly

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

What might the Latin be for this word. I first thought that the Plautine has litteras gallina scripsit might be modified but eventually went for ‘inter otia aninmi formas scribere’ and ‘formae inter otia animi scriptae’, after Quintilian Inst. Orat. 6, 2. Is this satisfactory in the view of colleagues?

Comment: Perhaps *(in cogitatione defixus) inanes/ineptas formas chartis illinere* (with apologies to Hor. Sat. 1, 4, 36)?

Comment: I like your suggestion, Sebastian! The modification of Horace is inspired. What might the noun be, based on  your answer? forma quasi. gallina illita?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say something like:

- *ōtiōsum* (either subject or object) or *ōtiōsē nescioquid dēlīneāre* > *dēlīneāmenta ōtiōsa;*

  - also *vānum, leve nescioquid;*
  - *scrībere* would probably refer to words;
- *in chartīs lūdere, calamō lūdere* > *(ōtiōsī) lūsūs calamī;*

  - also *in chartīs nūgās agere,* and the self-deprecatory *ineptīre;*
- *ōtiōsē līneās dūcere* > *līneae/ductūs* is as straightforward as I can think of.
- A literal equivalent of Plautus' playful saying (which btw is directly paralleled in Russian) is *rudis scrīptiō~scrīptūra/dēlīneātiō/pictūra.* However, both the literal and the chicken-disrespecting expression are concerned with making a negative evaluation – they don't mean 'absent-mindedly', but 'badly'.

  - *illinere* and the noun *litūra* are great options for this sense as well, but are about smearing, and so require either paint or copious amounts of ink to be involved.
- If I had to come up with an ad-hoc metaphor, or to imagine what metaphor could be used in Latin for children's scrawlings, it would be *vermiculī* 'little worms'. The same is used in New Latin of spaghetti, and [some Italian varieties](https://books.google.com/books?id=lewsAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA3) use *macaron* just this way, to refer to scrawlings (as well as ink blots).

  - Standard Italian uses words that appear to come from scarab beetles (*scarabocchio*) and scorpions (*sgorbio*). Perhaps they too started out in reference to ink blot shapes.
- Instead of *fōrmās* (which are 3-dimensional) I'd probably use *figūrās.*

Comment: mi Scytha, ex more tuo quod mihi tam diligenter, tam accurate, tam subtiliter respondistti valde gratum est. magno cum gaudio semper exspecto responsa tua quae omnes fere optiones quasi considerant atque commentantur. praeterea, sententiis aliorum trbuis laudem, etiam cum fortasse aliqua parte vitiosae vel in erratis esse videntur.

Comment: @JonathanHadfield Grātō animō legō quae scrībis, mī Jōhannē, praesertim quod et dē aliōrum sententiīs nihil laudis dētrahere videar, nam sānē difficile fit istud per scrīpta rētiālia significāre, respōnsa autem scrībere nūllā praestō sententiā, unde cōgitātiōne proficīscāris, difficilius.—Ceterum hīc nōn aliēnum vidētur adicere mē nescioan ob hanc ipsam causam īs quae quaeris rogāsque tam cupidē ac dīligenter respondēre. nam quōdam modō vidēris ea quaerere quae vel egomet in mediō quaererem sī modo spērāre audērem aliquem mē satis adjūtūrum. quod quidem maxumē tibi invicem praestāre nītor

Comment: pro ope tua, pro responso tuo,, pro inmerita mei laude, maximas tibi gratias.